# API Gateway Custom Domain Names

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Simple query, that hasn't seemed to have come up in the documentation, nor the AWS forums.

I have an API on my API Gateway, and a stage that has a Custom Domain name assigned to it. I need to rename this Domain name, is it possible?

[image]

From the looks of it, my only option would be to delete the domain, recreate it (re-attaching the certificates) and then assign it back to the same stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct - as you stated you will need to delete the domain, recreate it (re-attaching the certificates) and then assign it back to the same stage.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping there was a cli command for it, similar to renaming APIs... To confirm, deleting and creating a new domain won't affect the API in anyway correct?